# WordPress category & taxonomy loop with pagination

Tags: loop, pagination, taxonomy

I have two taxonomies belonging to the same post type (posts).

Adventure - belonging to the category taxonomy
Adventure - belonging to the holiday-type taxonomy

I want to run two queries:

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'holiday-types',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => 'adventure',
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'adventure',
                ),  
            ),

        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Even though the terms are the same they have different posts associated to them.

This query only returns posts with the holiday-types taxonomy and not the category taxonomy too. If I comment out the array with the holiday types, then the taxonomy category shows the relevant posts.

I need them to both show together as well as with pagination.

```
'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
```

I have read that i need to add this to the first array but i guess i cant test this until i get the loop working correctly first.

Any ideas where I am going wrong please?

---

Ok. I have got somewhere with this now but the pagination doesn't work. It goes to a 404 page when clicking through to the other pages e.g. 2, 3, 4. What is it I am missing?

```
global $query_string;
$myquery = wp_parse_args($query_string);
$myquery = array(
    'paged' => $paged,
    'numberposts'=>-1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'terms' => array('adventure'),
            'field' => 'slug',

        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'holiday-types',
            'terms' => array('adventure'),
            'field' => 'slug',
        ),        
    ),
 );
query_posts($myquery);

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_pagenavi();
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: your codes seems perfectly okay too me. I hope somebody soon help u out, all the best\

Comment: please show SQL of your `$the_query` obj by `var_dump($the_query->request)`

Comment: By default the results are paginated according to the setting in your Reading Settings for "Blog pages show at most", if you haven't set up pagination yet are you sure it's not just that the first N results are from the Holiday Types taxonomy?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `'numberposts'=>-1` because numberposts is depracated moreover -1 shows all the post on one page.

Instead use `posts_per_page` and set its value according to how many posts do you want.

```
$paged= (get_query_var('paged' )) ? get_query_var('paged'):1; 
global $query_string;
$myquery = wp_parse_args($query_string);
$myquery = array(
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page'=>10,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'terms' => array('adventure'),
            'field' => 'slug',

        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'holiday-types',
            'terms' => array('adventure'),
            'field' => 'slug',
        ),        
    ),
 );
query_posts($myquery);

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_pagenavi();
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: `numberposts` is not depreciated, but it is an invalid parameter for `query_posts` (*which you should really not use*), `numberposts` is used with `get_posts` but does get converted to `posts_per_page` before being passed to `WP_Query`

Comment: @Pieter Goosen thanks for the valuable informatiom